# Physics type animations for floating bubbles

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I am currently prototyping making a screen with bubbles (circular xml drawables for now) that have a start and end position and animate in a floating bubble fashion.

I am currently using the new Motion Layout provided in the Constraint Layout alpha build and right now it is both proving a pain to adjust the values (eagerly awaiting the timeline animation tool) or never looking correct.

Is anyone aware of a library that has similar functionality or is Motion Layout the best bet?

Whenever i look for bubble stuff it is regarding the ripple effect on buttons etc and so it's proving a little tough to find anything.

I would ideally like to be able to add bubbles dynamically with a start and end point and then start animations independently but just getting the animations looking right is the main goal right now.

As aside question - does anyone know the official/expected release date for Constraint Layout 2?

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, we're looking to implement the same.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @MickByrne Android Canary build just released today has the Motion Layout editor.  I've not looked at it yet but this may help with creating the animations.. https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-studio-40-canary-1-available.html

Comment: Android Studios 4.0 (now in stable channel) has the motion editor.  https://youtu.be/f1fHPqAYj5I